# Straight lines diving the plane

Tags: geometry

I got this from a book. They made this assertion as part of a proof and said it is obvious why. But I have a problem explaining why it is the case.

Let us assume that we have $k$ lines such that no two are parallel and no three pass through a single point. If we add a ($k+1$)th line such that these properties hold it will pass through $k+1$ pieces into which the plane is divided.

Going from 1 line to two is pretty straight forward. We have two half-planes that into which the first line divided the plane. Since the lines aren't parallel it will go through both of them.

This is also true when we have 2 lines and add a 3rd one.
[image]

If I visualise it I can see it is the case, but what is the reasoning behind this for any $k$ and $k+1$?

Comment: Each time the new line crosses one of the old lines, it moves into a different region. It will cross each of the old lines once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to remember is what was written: no two lines are parallel, and no three
lines all pass through the same point.

That means when you add the $(k+1)$th line $L$ to a set of $k$ lines,
line $L$ must cross each of the other $k$ lines, since it is not parallel to any of them.
Moreover, all the crossings look like this:

[image]

None of the crossings look like this:

[image]

So the crossings occur at $k$ different places (one for each line, never two at once).
And each time there is a crossing, you end up with four separate regions 
(labeled $A,B,C,D$ in the figure above)
where there were only two separate regions
($A$ combined with $C$, and $B$ combined with $D$)
bordered by the first $k$ lines.

To see that you *can* always draw such a line $L$ (neither parallel to
any of the others nor intersecting any two others in the same point),
pick a point on the plane and draw lines through that point parallel to
each of the $k$ existing lines. Now take two of those lines that form an angle
with no other line "between" them, and bisect that angle.
This is just one example of a line not parallel to any of the first $k$ lines.

Once you have found a line not parallel to any of the first $k$, what if
it happens to intersect two of them at the same point?
Consider *all* the points where any of the first $k$ lines intersect.
There are only a finite number of such points, because each pair of lines
intersects in only one point and there are only so many pairs; there are
$\frac12k(k-1)$ such points, in fact, but let's just say there are $n$ such points.
So if $L'$ is a line not parallel to any of the first $k$ lines,
there are at most $n$ lines parallel to $L'$ (possibly including $L'$ itself)
that intersect two of the first $k$ lines simultaneously.
So pick *any* *other* line parallel to $L'$, and call it $L$;
it is not parallel to any of the first $k$ lines, and it does not intersect
any two of those lines in the same point.

This explanation itself relies on the assumption that you are doing this
in Euclidean geometry, and on a number of facts about that geometry
that are themselves "obvious". You could always dig deeper, but I think the
point was that actually arranging all the lines starts to look too complicated
when $k$ is large. The idea is to break down the procedure of adding new lines
to a sequence of simple steps so you never have to consider anything too
complicated in any one step.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But why is the bisector not parallel to any of the other lines?

Comment: Maybe a better way to look at it is, draw an arbitrary line in the plane and start rotating it counterclockwise (or clockwise). As you rotate the line, at certain instants in time it will be parallel to one of the $k$ lines. But in between those times it will not be parallel to any of them. The "bisector" is just a way (maybe too complicated a way) to identify one of those times in between the "is parallel" events.